# Redux Toolkit Typescript Error: How to use an object in an action payload?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm receiving an error in Typescript for a React Redux Action, which is coded as below

```
// createSlice.ts
export const myStateSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'myState',
  initialState: myInitState,
  reducers: {
    setState: (state: any, action: PayloadAction<{ mode: string; value: any }>) => {
       // doing stuff that works fine in Javascript
    },
});
export const {setState} = myStateSlice.actions
```

Then, in another file, I get an error when calling:

```
// doingstuff.ts
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(setState({mode:'string', value:{aThing: anotherThing})); // error
```

This all works fine in Javascript. However, when I convert the .js to .ts, I receive the message below, and I have no idea what to do about it. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

> Argument of type '{ payload: { mode: string; value: any; }; type:
> string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload<{ state: string; value: any; },
> string>'.   Property 'match' is missing in type '{ payload: { mode:
> string; value: any; }; type: string; }' but required in type
> 'ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload<{ mode: string; value: any; },
> string>'.ts(2345)

Thank you!

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: On the dispatch call, edited question.

Comment: I am having the same error essentially